Por que no se puede modificar directamente una posicion de un texto en javascript
Quiero cambiar la primera letra de cada string del array a mayúscula,  y el siguiente código no funciona, pero no entiendo el por que?
introducir el código aquí
function capitalizarNombres_2(nombres){
    for (const key in nombres) {
       nombres[key][0] = (nombres[key].toUpperCase())[0];
    }
  return(nombres);
}

capitalizarNombres_2(["maria", "carlos", "ana", "pedro"]);
Resultado esperado
["Maria", "Carlos", "Ana", "Pedro"]
Resultado obtenido
["maria", "carlos", "ana", "pedro"]
En javascript no se puede modificar directamente el contenido de una posición de una cadena ?, yo trato de modificar la posición 0 de cada cadena del array.

En javascript los string son inmutables, quiere decir que una vez se hayan  creado, su contenido no puede ser alterado. Y eso tiene como efecto que es seguro ya que previene errores inesperados en el código.
Por ejemplo en este caso nombre = "maria" si lo intentas modificar con nombre[0] = "M", este ignora esa asignación y lo deja sin efecto.


let nombre = "maria";
nombre[0] = "M"; // Ignora la operación
console.log(nombre);



En cambio debes crear un nuevo string con los cambios que deseas como lo puedes hacer con método substring


let nombre = "maria";
nombre = "M" + nombre.substring(1);  // Crea una nuevo string
console.log(nombre);



Por ende, tu código debería quedar así:


function capitalizarNombres_2(nombres) {
  for (let i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
    nombres[i] = nombres[i][0].toUpperCase() + nombres[i].substring(1); //concatena con el método substring
  }
  return nombres;
}

console.log(capitalizarNombres_2(["maria", "carlos", "ana", "pedro"]));




Mil gracias por la respuesta, ahora me queda claro

Con esto lo puedes realizar:


console.log( capitalizarNombres_2(["maria", "carlos", "ana", "pedro"]) );
function capitalizarNombres_2(nombres){
    for (const key in nombres) {
        let letra = '' ;
        letra = nombres[key][0].toUpperCase();
        nombres[key] = letra + nombres[key].slice(1);
    }
  return(nombres);
}



